# How can i use form2's data on Form1 in delphi 7.2

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Okay I'm still at school and quite new to this. I have a form2 that is a log in page where the user will enter a password and name. How would I be able to use the entered data on the other form1 ?

Comment: There is no delphi 7.2. Stop using pirate software.

Comment: For any school purposes you can replace pirated Delphi 7 with Lazarus/CodeTyphon

Comment: Thanks for the help, And I didn't download any software, it was given to me by our teacher and we use it at school. Wasn't aware that Delphi 7 second edition is probable pirate software.

Comment: There is no such thing as *Delphi 7 second edition*.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to have "uses form2" in your form1.

Typically show form2 as modal something like

```
unit form1;
...
uses
    form2;
...
procedure TForm1.Login;
var username, password: string;
begin
  if Form2.ShowModal = mrOK then
  begin
     username := Form2.UsernameEdit;
     password := Form2.PasswordEdit;
     {do login stuff}
  end;
end;
```